# Bring SwiftUI ButtomSheet behind tab bar

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

I want to use the new iOS 16 Buttom Sheet Feature to create a view like the find my:

[image]

Unfortunately the TabView gets hidden behind the Sheet:

[image]

My Code:

```
           TabView {
            Text("View 1")
                .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                    Text("Sheet View Content")
                        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
        
            Text("View 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Order", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
        }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would try to put text and sheet in a VStack. So the sheet is not associated with the tabview but the VStack

Answer (score 5):

**No Solution for the moment**

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to show a modal sheet with a tab bar visible using the current version of SwiftUI. This issue has been raised by other developers on the Apple developer forums and on other threads on StackOverflow, such as the following:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711702
- [Swift UI show modal sheet with tab bar visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427775/swift-ui-show-modal-sheet-with-tab-bar-visible)
- [SwiftUI present sheet in a TabItem of TabView using presentationDetents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74685259/swiftui-present-sheet-in-a-tabitem-of-tabview-using-presentationdetents)

*I am also searching for a solution to this problem.*

I am currently working on a custom `ViewModifier` to address this issue, and if it is successful, I will make it publicly available on GitHub.

Comment: @Arnaud - Do you have it working?