# SwiftUI present sheet in a TabItem of TabView using presentationDetents

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-sheet

I am trying to create the same experience where a sheet is presented in one of the tab items of a TabView - not covering the tabs.
I am using .presentationDetents() and SwiftUI4.0 for that.

[See example of Apple's own app doing that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETAkN.jpg)
The sheet is covering the child view inside TabView.

However, instead in my own code I am getting
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLeho.jpg) - the tabs of the parent view are covered by the modal sheet

Comment: Found this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427775/swift-ui-show-modal-sheet-with-tab-bar-visible

looks like a similar issue with no resolution.

Comment: And another one here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711702

Answer (score 0):

The link https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711702 suggests that it is not possible to achieve the same behaviour you see in Apple's Maps and Find My apps with the current SwiftUI API.